# Quicker way to visit web site item details from a list implemented with JavaScript instead of a link

Tags: website, javascript, browser-addons, navigation

### Scenario

The user visits a web page that presents a **list of items** and the user desires to **visit every item in the list**.  Rather than each item having a unique URL, the website is implemented such that **each item instead runs javascript (not a link)** to show item details.  When clicked, the javascript runs and takes the user to the specific item details, leaving the list of items.  Now the user would like to go to the next item in the list, but that requires going back to the list of items.  The website implementation details are of course not under the control of the user.

- Problem 1: Many sites take a long time to regenerate the list.
- Problem 2: The user must coordinate which items have been
  visited, so selecting the next item can take a long time.

In sites that are implemented with unique URLs, the solution is easy: right-click the URL and select 'open link in new tab', repeat for all items, then inspect every open tab to get the desired information.

In sites that are implemented with javascript, this technique does not work because 'open link in new tab' is not present because the clickable element is not a link, but rather causes javascript to run, which forwards to the details page.

### Question

Is there a way to more quickly access all details pages in a list when it is implemented as specified in the above scenario?

### Experimentation

I have tried several approaches because I have encountered this problem often while accessing many different sites.  One thing that sometimes works, but can not be counted upon is to inspect the source to see if there is a key somewhere on the list item HTML source that also appears in the details page URL (as exposed by *Web Developer Tools > Network*).  For this question, let's presume this method does not work due to the website implementation; I've found the URL that has the detailed data often is just one of those long random-looking strings.  And although inspecting the javascript source on the page is possible, it's probably to the point of diminishing returns at that point (would take too long to figure out).

Optimally, there would be a way to access the *open link in new tab* functionality on a list item with javascript implementation.  Something like *open the javascript defined page in new tab*.

Comment: Does the site have proper URLs that could just be generated from item IDs or whatever?

Comment: @DanielB No, there seems to be no way to divine from the page content a URL where the detailed item can be found.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not visiting a web page (in the traditional sense) but rather a web application. **Unless this web application is designed to have proper URLs, you are out of luck.** It is simply not feasible, just like you can’t have Notepad open and then show the font selection dialog. Well, technically you can, but more on that later.

Good web applications have proper URLs for all views, often using the `History.pushState` browser API. That means even though what you click on may not be a link, you could still guess the target URL (`http://www.example.com/items/1234`) from the contents (hidden elements, element IDs, attributes) or whatever. These good URLs are sometimes also referred to as permalinks or deep links.

Bad web applications don’t use the URL at all or not properly. That means you have to do some or even all the steps to arrive at the desired view. *This is not feasible*. Especially when, like you describe it, some interactions are very slow.

Still, it can be done, using UI automation tools. Examples of such tools, which may not individually get you all the way: AutoHotKey, Playwright, Selenium. Furthermore, it is possible to do this using browser extensions or possibly even a bookmarklet. All of this requires programming and sometimes extensively diving into the web apps inner workings.